# Iterating through a list in python to check file line lenghth

Tags: python, list, file, line

I've been at this problem for hours and no matter what I throw at it I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

The objective is to import a file which contains 12 numbers each line for however many lines the user wants to input. (it's checking UPC codes). What I'm trying to do is import the file, and then set up a loop to check EACH line in the file, and if it is over 12 characters long or under it spits out an error, also if it contains any letters it spits out an error (i'm not to this point yet.) 
Anyhow, here's my code:

```
iven = input("what is the file name")
infile = open(iven, "r")
lines = infile.read()
v = lines.split()
print(lines)
print(v)


for i in range(len(v)):
    if len(v[i]) > 12:
        print("UPC is too long")
    elif len(v[i]) < 12:
        print("UPC is too short")
    else:
        print(v)
```

And as of right now it's a mess. I can either make it read the text document one character at a time or it counts the entire thing, it just will not go line by line. Any question's i could help you with this please just ask away

Comment: You should probably either use `readlines` instead of `read`; or `split("\n")` instead of `split()`.

Comment: What is the input format? What is the expected output or behaviour? I think there are easier ways to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating over the file object directly yields data from the file line by line

```
iven = input("what is the file name")
with open(iven) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()  # presumably you're not interested in any newline characters
        if len(line) > 12:
            print("UPC is too long")
        elif len(line) < 12:
            print("UPC is too short")
        elif not line.isdigit():
            print("UPC isn't a number")
        else:
            print(v)
```

Alternatively, if you just want to check the file has no lines less, or greater than 12 characters (maybe you want `line.rstrip()` here too)

```
if all(len(line.rsplit()) == 12 and line.rsplit().isdigit() for line in open(iven)):
    print("All good!")
```

Comment: Maybe you could `all(line[12] and int(line) for line in open(iven))` and catch an exception.

Comment: @ReutSharabani `line[12]` checks the 13th character, so it would error for valid input. I did miss the point about checking if the lines are numbers though.

Comment: you mean that this is a wrong approach (it is, sometimes...) or that it should be line[11]? because I can't edit the comment anymore :(. I see now that the `all` is redundant when doing this.

Comment: @ReutSharabani it should be `line[11]` in your example, but this would only error for when `line` is less than 12 characters- and not if it is over 12 characters

Comment: oh, I see! totally missed that! `isdigit` is the better option.

Comment: @marineau yea it would but I'm supposed to report back to the user why something didn't work, so being specific if the line was too short or too long is needed

Comment: @GP89 Thank you very much this works wonderfully, fantastic job and thank you for the quick response!